# Which object is the sender while performing a segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a segue in a table view controller, and I want to declare an identifier in the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"noteSegue" sender:________];
}
```

But I'm trying to understand who is the sender here...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the object that is passed to `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`, you can pass `nil` here without worry if you like (and don't implement `prepareForSegue`).

For segues created in the interface builder, `sender` will be the object bound to execute the segue.

Answer (score 2):

The sender is also self, it is the instance of the ViewController that is the initial start of the segue and is what you should write if you are using StoryBoards.